# Can't find my Mailable class from Route::get

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting this error in Laravel while trying to get from route method. My error is:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
>
> **(E_ERROR) Class 'NewUserWelcomeMail' not found**

My route method is:

```
Route::get('/email', function() {
  return new NewUserWelcomeMail();
});
```

NewUserWelcomeMail class code is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class NewUserWelcomeMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.welcome-email');
    }
}
```

I tried this as this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImtZ5yENzgE) said but don't understand why my one is not working as all rest are working fine. Video time from 4:13:00.

Comment: use this code `return new \App\Mail\NewUserWelcomeMail();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the namespace. Change your route code to the following:

```php
Route::get('/email', function() {
  return new \App\Mail\NewUserWelcomeMail();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using laravel 7+
You can try changing your web route to:

```
Route::get('/email', function () {
return new \App\Mail\NewUserWelcomeMail();});
```

then your user model like so:

```
Mail::to($user->email)->send(new \App\Mail\NewUserWelcomeMail());
```